# R - putting coordinates together

Tags: r, vector, coordinates

I want a list of coordinate points in [0,1] x [0,1]. Suppose I have

```
 x = seq(0,1, length.out = 100)
 y = seq(0,1, length.out = 100)
```

I want to combine them so that I get a 100 x 100 matrix with each possible coordinate in [0,1] that I defined. So I would like to get a data frame M of the form

```
M[i,j] = c(x[i], x[j])
```

with i and j ranging from 1 to 100

Edit. Here is an example of the output I want. Take

```
x = c(0,0.5, 1)
y = c(0,0.5,1)


M = c(0,0)    c(0,0.5)      c(0,1)
    c(0.5,0)  c(0.5, 0.5)   c(0.5,1)
    c(1,0)    c(1,0.5)      c(1,1)
```

I would like each of the entries to be vectors of class numeric. 
For why I want this, I just want to draw a two dimensional lattice with lines between each ('neighbouring') coordinate in M. Ie., edges are  (M[i,j], M[i, j+1]) and (M[i,j], M[i+1,j]) for when this makes sense.

Comment: Can you give an example of how you want the final result to look?

Comment: Not sure this is clear. You can create a 100x100 matrix easy enough `matrix(rep(NA,100*100),100,100)` but how do you want it to relate to your coordinates? What are you trying to do?

Comment: sorry. I want all possible coordinate possibilities. Something like M[i,j] = c(x[i], y[j]) for i in 1:100, j in 1:100

Comment: You cannot have an element of a matrix as a vector. You can have it as a string. Refer to my answer for the code.

Answer (score 4):

This should do it,

```
a <- 11:20
b <- 11:20

allCombs <- outer(a,b,paste)
```

Use your vectors instead of a and b.

If you don't want them as strings, and want it as a matrix, it's not possible as an element of a matrix cannot be a vector. What you can do, if you need to use these to refer somewhere else is use, expand.grid.

```
a <- 11:20
b <- 11:20

allCombs <- expand.grid(a,b)
```

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

```
M <- data.frame(matrix(nrow=length(x), ncol=length(y)))
for(i in sequence(length(x))){
  for(j in sequence(length(y))){
    M[i,j] <- paste0("[", i, ",", j, "]")
  }
}
```